# Clear URL bar on tab load

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

I am writing a Firefox addon and it opens a page in the addon instead of the blank page for a new tab, but it has the URL in the url bar which I would like to be empty. How do I clear the url bar?

For example, is it something like: `gURLBar.clear();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out my problem, I just use this: `gURLBar.value = "";`